# This errors kills the process of running nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm getting following error simultaneously.

This error occurs in Terminal :

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
ca[6517:0x491af90]   389479 ms: Mark-sweep 2047.1 (2055.3) -> 2046.4 (2056.3) MB, 1381.3 / 0.1 ms  (+ 270.2 ms in 38 steps since start of marking, biggest step 19.1 ms, walltime since start of marking 1686 ms) (average mu = 0.099, current mu = 0.021) alloca[6517:0x491af90]   391293 ms: Mark-sweep 2048.5 (2056.3) -> 2047.9 (2057.3) MB, 1098.9 / 0.1 ms  (+ 685.1 ms in 36 steps since start of marking, biggest step 499.1 ms, walltime since start of marking 1814 ms) (average mu = 0.055, current mu = 0.017) alloc

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x13555cd]
Security context: 0x0b156f1008d1 <JSObject>
    1: slice [0x2a241b8bfa91] [buffer.js:~606] [pc=0x2fa7af85cfa6](this=0x2a241b8bfd79 <Object map = 0x9514c326099>,0x3b30a44ce789 <Uint8Array map = 0x9514c3255a9>,52288,52523)
    2: parseLengthCodedString [0x3f349708d1f1] [/home/abc/Block-Exporter/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:~148] [pc=0x2fa7af5e63e3](this=0x157d3bf8b519 <Parser map = 0x3427fbc0985...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa093f0 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa097fc node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb842ae v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb84629 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xd30fe5  [node]
 6: 0xd31676 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
 7: 0xd3def5 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xd3eda5 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xd4185c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xd0f74c v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
11: 0xd0ff0d v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromUtf8(v8::internal::Vector<char const> const&, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
12: 0xb9c60f v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::NewStringType, int) [node]
13: 0xae34b0 node::StringBytes::Encode(v8::Isolate*, char const*, unsigned long, node::encoding, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) [node]
14: 0x9e35a6  [node]
15: 0x13555cd  [node]
```

And This occurs in console :

```
react-dom.development.js:88 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
in AccountAllDetail (created by Connect(AccountAllDetail))
in Connect(AccountAllDetail) (created by Route)
```

I did this `export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"`. but it didn't work for me.

I can't find the right answer anywhere.

I'm adding code snap for particular js file below. Please look inside.

This is inside AccountAllDetail.js:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;

    this.findData();
    this.findTransactions();
    this.findWitnesses();
    this.findCommittee();
    this.findOperations();
    if(!!this.account[1] && this.account[1].includes('1.2'))
        this.setState({activeTab: '1'});
    else if(!!this.account[1] && this.account[1].includes('1.6'))
        this.setState({activeTab: '3'});
    else if(!!this.account[1] && this.account[1].includes('1.5'))
        this.setState({activeTab: '4'});
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props !== prevProps) {
        this.findData();
        this.findTransactions();
        this.findWitnesses();
        this.findCommittee();
        this.findOperations();

        if(!!this.account[1] && this.account[1].includes('1.2'))
            this.setState({activeTab: '1'});
        else if(!!this.account[1] && this.account[1].includes('1.6'))
            this.setState({activeTab: '3'});
        else if(!!this.account[1] && this.account[1].includes('1.5'))
            this.setState({activeTab: '4'});
    }
}
```

Comment: are you doing any kind of serverside rendering?

Comment: Yes. There is huge amount of data which i need to render.

Comment: componentdidmount is never called while the component is rendered serverside